# How to migrate product and categories from asp.net ecommrece to magento?

Tags: asp.net, magento

I have ecommerce website in Asp.net. I want to migrate my ecommerce website to Magento.
How can I migrate products and categories from Asp.net website to magento website?

Answer (score 1):

In case you lack the necessary knowledge to do it yourself, I would suggest you try a migration tool. There's a bunch of them on the market and as far as I know the majority offer a free demo option. So, you're not risking anything. My personal preference is Cart2Cart. I used to migrate my stores a couple of times already.
What's great about an automated migration that there's a minimal involvement in the process. You kinda configure the options and that's it. The price is reasonable too

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this you need to hire a magento developer or team, who can migrate your product, services and categories from asp.net to magento store using best magento conversion services.